# How can I add a new endpoint for WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to add a new endpoint in WooCommerce and the new endpoint I added should work  just like WooCommerce's own endpoints.

For example it should get the validations from WooCommerce.

Or consumer key and consumer secret key checks should be automated.

How do I do this? a hook or action maybe?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Sorry for my bad english

My goal was to add a new REST API Endpoint in WooCommerce and this endpoint should be have like any other WooCommerce REST API.
So the new rest api to add is WooCommerce.
It should cover validation and other features that the rest api's have.

My solution for now is this:

```
<?php
/*
    Plugin Name: Umut API
    Description: WooCommerce API deneme eklentisi.
    Version: 1.0
    Author: Umut
    Text Domain: @@@
    Domain Path: /lang
*/
require_once ABSPATH. 'wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/rest-api/Controllers/Version3/class-wc-rest-controller.php';
include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-rest-authentication.php';
include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\rest-api\Controllers\Version3\class-wc-rest-posts-controller.php';

class WC_REST_Custom_Controller extends WC_REST_Posts_Controller{

    protected $namespace = 'wc/v3';

    protected $rest_base = 'custom';

    protected $post_type = 'custom_umut';

    public function get_custom( $data ) {
        return ['cevap' => 'get çalıştı'];
    }

    public function post_custom( $data ){
        return ['cevap' => 'post çalıştı'];
    }

    public function register_routes() {
        register_rest_route(
            $this->namespace,
            '/' . $this->rest_base,
            array(
                'methods' => 'GET',
                'callback' => array( $this, 'get_custom' ),
                'permission_callback' => array( $this, 'get_items_permissions_check' ),
            )
        );
        register_rest_route(
            $this->namespace,
            '/' . $this->rest_base,
            array(
                'methods' => 'POST',
                'callback' => array( $this, 'post_custom' ),
                'permission_callback' => array( $this, 'get_items_permissions_check' ),
            )
        );
    }
}

add_action( 'init', function( ){

    wc_register_order_type(
        'custom_umut',
        apply_filters(
            'woocommerce_register_post_type_shop_order',
            array(
                'labels'=> array(
                    'name'                  => 'custom',
                ),
                'description'         => __( 'This is where store orders are stored.', 'woocommerce' ),
            )
        )
    );
});

add_filter('woocommerce_rest_api_get_rest_namespaces', 'woo_custom_api');

function woo_custom_api( $controllers ) {
    $controllers['wc/v3']['custom'] = 'WC_REST_Custom_Controller';
    return $controllers;
}

?>
```

Comment: Are you talking about the Rest API? https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Comment: yes but that rest api like must be woocommerce rest api

Comment: Whatever functionality you implement _behind_ those endpoints, is up to you.

Comment: what I am trying to say is to derive the new endpoint to be added from WooCommerce.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a new REST API route, You can use the `register_rest_route` WordPress Methode for [registering a new route](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/).
But if you want to add a Frontend endpoint there are multiple solutions:

1. using `add_shortcode` for [registering a new shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/).
2. using `add_rewrite_endpoint` for [registering new uri endpoint](https://awhitepixel.com/blog/custom-url-endpoints-wordpress-rewrite-api/).
3. using [Page templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/)

also here is a complete reference of [woocommerce hooks](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/hooks/hooks.html) for use in your codes.